# Tkinter: How do I handle menus with many items?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-menu

If I have a menu with too many items to fit on the screen, how do I get one of those 'more' buttons with a downward arrow at the bottom of the menu? Is that supported?

Comment: Consider to put them in a canvas.

Answer (score -1):

simply You can add a scrollbar to that widget

```
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()
scrollbar = Scrollbar(master)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
listbox = Listbox(master, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
for i in range(1000):
    listbox.insert(END, str(i))
listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)
mainloop()
```

add your menu code..this is code for listbox with Yscroll

Comment: Hmm. It still doesn't seem to work, since Menu objects don't have the yscrollcommand keyword like Listbox objects do. Let me know if I'm misunderstanding you, somehow. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem with cascading menus. I already had some, but I didn't want to use more for these particular menus items—but after closer inspection, I think it's better this way.

I'm still interested in other solutions, for scenarios where cascading menus are not a practical option, however (like if the screen is too narrow to cascade that far or something). So, I don't plan to mark this as the accepted answer anytime soon (even though in most circumstances, it's probably the best solution).